# Flash the Bios without a screen

Tags: display, bios, flashing

Could i create a batch file that would run an executable automatically
without any type of control when I insert the USB flash drive and power up.
I have no screen, and I need to flash the Bios.
Its a Asus B550M-A with UEFI AMI Bios 2803 I have read on a few sites that the Ryzen 5000 series CPU's are incompatible with B550M-A. They say that the BIOS must be flashed. I was thinking about the batch file, because there are only 2 files on the USB drive, Bios renamer.exe and the Bios file itself.

Comment: If the BIOS supports this, yes. What system, what main board, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Its a Asus B550M-A with UEFI AMI Bios 2803 I have read on a few sites that the Ryzen 5000 series CPU's are incompatible with B550M-A. They say that the BIOS must be flashed. I was thinking about the batch file, because there are only 2 files on the USB drive, Bios renamer.exe and the Bios file itself. If I can figure this out, I could help a lot of people.

Comment: The way to do it, if possible is by triggering a special flashing mode with an USB stick containing the UEFI file connected. It's NOT how you're asking here. Batch files need an OS to run. Please consult your user's manual.

Comment: When we ask for more information, use the edit button and add the requested information to the question itself. The question needs to get better, and editing is ENCOURAGED in order to accomplish this

Comment: So do you think the different boards that have a Bios flashback button and a special USB port, need to start an OS?

Comment: @Sr2 No, that's the exact opposite of what I said above. The flashing mode has nothing to do with an OS, it doesn't even need a drive let alone an installed OS. And it has nothing to do with batch files. You're the one talking about batch files, I merely corrected that misconception. Of the 2 files you mentioned one, the .exe, is to be run from Windows (it may or may not run from a bootable FreeDOS USB stick but with that you need a monitor); the .bin file is the actual UEFI update and can be used from inside the UEFI settings (again, monitor needed) or via the aforementioned method.